# How can we open Google chrome as a different user using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open Chrome browser 'As a different user' using the Selenium with Python. HOw can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, just `add_argument` to `chrome_options`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
```